# using db4o with netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have downloaded db4o-8.0 and i'm attempting to use it in netbeans, however when I try using:

```
    import com.db4o.(anything I try import);
```

then it comes up with the error:

```
     error: package com.db4o does not exist import com.db4o.(anything I try import)
```

I have tried importing the downloaded folder as a library, i've tried using it as a source package, and it still brings up the same errors.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to compile the project outside the NetBeans by executing:

- `ant build` for Ant projects
- `mvn install` for Maven projects

If it fails, then you did not import the library or the imported library does not contain the class files (look and expand the files in JAR file).

Comment: I'm just using a general java project, and the library contains all the required files,  which is why i'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Can you take s screenshot or provide the source base?

Comment: I changed it into a maven class and it managed to correct itself after being built with dependencies, thanks for the help :)